# iOS8 Swift - Problems dynamically resizing tableview cells

Tags: swift, dynamic, ios8, resize, tableview

[Here's what my application looks like currently.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv0z0.png)

You'll see that when the subtitle text label is only one line is resizes correctly, but when there's multiple lines it gets all messed up. I think this has to do with the constraints possibly? Right now I'm using the auto-layout constraints. You can see them in the screenshot. Here's the code that creates my cells.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> DealCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Deal Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as DealCell

    let currentBar = bars[indexPath.row] as BarAnnotation
    cell.barName.text = currentBar.name
    cell.deal.text = currentBar.deal
    cell.distanceToBar.text = String(format: "%.3f mi", currentBar.distance)

    // Set the height of the table view cells
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;

    return cell
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` function in the UITableViewDelegate.
Using this you can individually set the height of each row separately.

For more information : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Or you can use auto layout settings like in this article.
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/02/14/table-view-cells-with-varying-row-heights.html

Comment: That is the same thing as setting the height when I create the cell. I think my question should have been titled "Problems with constraints on dynamically resized cells". The issue is when the label is more than one line it's not being constrained properly as shown in the picture.